# Clustering a Spatial Raster Stack

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, geospatial, spatial, terra

I 'm trying to combine different (spatial) datasets to find similar patterns of the combination of these factors. I am working with terra and spatial rasters. For trying to find the patterns I am trying to either get a k-means or BIC cluster.

I have done this code:

```
#I am stacking the different rasters together (they have the same extent and resolution)
stack1 <- c(resamp.pop, eleva.rec.tif, resamp.lc, resamp.lc.bare)
#need to make matrix to create a cluster
val <- values(stack1)
#do the cluster
k.clust <- kmeans(na.omit(val), centers = 10)

#create raster with same dimensions as stack1
krast <- stack1
values(krast) <- k.clust$cluster
plot(krast)
```

However, this has created very weird patterns and has not clustered it at all by combining the different patterns instead I am returned with a random pattern and clusters. Does anyone have a better idea on how I could be combining these?
I would also be very happy to have a different package suggested that can maybe also do a kmeans or BIC clustering of spatial data(preferably the data combined), as I think the problem might come from the transformation into the matrix.

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to take care of the cells that are NA. Here is an approach you can take

Example data

```
library(terra)
s <- rast(system.file("ex/logo.tif", package="terra"))   
s[10:20,] <- NA
```

Solution

```
# get cell numbers and values for cells that are not NA
d <- as.data.frame(s, cell=TRUE)
    
k.clust <- kmeans(d[,-1], centers = 5)
krast <- rast(s, nlyr=1)
krast[d$cell] <- k.clust$cluster
```

Comment: Hi Robert, thank you for your answer! My problem sadly isn't the NA values. I have taken care of them, as the algorithm would not run otherwise. I am more having the issue that it is just not putting them right into the thing. I will be trying to put it into a dataframe instead though, so thank you!

Comment: The problem *is* that you remove the NA values --- you need to for kmeans, but then you also need to take that into consideration when assigning the values back to a raster.